# OQPSK - GNU Radio Companion

Tags: modulation, gnuradio, oqpsk

I was wondering if anyone has had any success in implementing OQPSK in gnuradio.

I have a working theory of expanding on the Constellation Modulator to include a custom OQPSK function.

I have already reviewed a few post, but what has been done seems too complicated.

I am wanting to learn so any reading material, etc, would be appreciated.

Feel free to comment!

Comment: Have you implemented something as simple QPSK already?

Comment: Yes I have. Utilizing the Constellation Modulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your Constellation Modulator generates two samples per symbol and you delay the Q output by one sample, then you get OQPSK, don't you?

Demodulating is much more complicated because I and Q get mixed up due to frequency/phase offsets so you cannot just delay I to synchronize it again with Q.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Once the synchronized IF carrier is established, then I think demodulation is pretty easy.  But synthesizing a synchronized carrier is tricky and I am curious at what is the most elegant way to do that.  [I posted a question about this synchronization.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79432/optimal-idle-or-frame-sync-symbols-for-oqpsk)